# Remove tabs from activities in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, tasks, activities, activity

I want to delete tabs in activities, and just let new task.

Help me
capture bellow :

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For removing the actions in Lightning, Go to Setup->Object Manager then select the object. Go to page layouts and edit the Page layout currently assigned. Under "Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions" you can keep the ones you need and remove the ones not needed (If the actions are not displayed, click on the "override the predefined actions").

[image: Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions]

Select this as the best answer if this resolves your issue.